# Selecting a block of members in PDS directory for editing

Tags: mainframe, zos, ispf

I want to select a group of members in a PDS for editing but unlike in SDSF, putting // in the beginning and end of block doesn't work.
Does anybody know how can I do that? For viewing a range of PDS members! is that even possible??

I appreciate your opinion on this.

[This is what I mean of selecting a block of members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mazCf.png)

Comment: If you read the user guide you will see that if you enter multiple 's' commands (which is what you are doing by a shorthand method) only the first is accepted and the others ignored. If you want to do what you are trying then write a program to select each member one by one and invoke edit on each selection.

Comment: You can edit all members by specifying `s *` on the command line, or specify an `s` beside each member you want to edit and then hit enter.

Comment: The S command operands is a limited filer, you can issue `S CB*` to select all members beginning with CB. You can also issue the `FILTER` command specifying operands as well. (Be aware that the `NAME` filter is limited to prefixes; specifying a mask on the VIEW/EDIT/Library Utility panel is more flexible.)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the dataset via option 3.4, the DSLIST command or the ISPF Workplace (usually option 11 and the best option).

Make sure that the 'Enhanced member list for Edit, View, and Browse' option is selected. This can be found in the 'options -> DSLIST' menu.

Enter 'e' against multiple members or use e * to select all members or e abc* to select all members beginning with abc and press 'enter'.

When you press PF3 to finish editing one member, you will be taken straight into edit on the next member.